# Sorting in Endeca Typeahead

Tags: endeca, oracle-commerce

We are using endeca dimension search for the typeahead search for autosuggestion and the search happens for a particular dimension.  So I have two questions:

1. As Dimension search doesn't support Sorting by default. is there any customization possible to sort the results based on some other property which is not part of dimension search results?
2. Dimension search does not support interface also, so is it possible
   to customize the dimension search to include more properties to be
   searched.

Please let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Dimension search is the functionality can be searched based on dimensions only not based on record properties so interface concept is not there. You can add some properties as part of dimension synonyms so that if someone searches for synonyms than actual dimension value can be appeared.

Dimension/Record search does not support sort as search should be based on relevance ranking. You can use relevance ranking algorithm to tweak the results as per requirements.

Thanks,
Ajay Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to** "is it possible to customize the dimension search to include more properties to be searched " **::**

Multiple properties can be included in the dimension search. Please check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_urlparams_di.html for reference.

Regarding how Endeca sort the dimensions results, see the DK and DX parameters - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_urlparams_dk.html  and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/webhelp/mdex_basicDev/src/rbdv_urlparams_dx.html.

Here, you can have a different DX option like Dx=rel+exact,static(nbins,descending) where the nbins is used to sort data and which results in sorting of refinement values according to their frequency of appearance within a data set.

**Answer to** " is there any customization possible to sort the results based on some other property which is not part of dimension search results" **::**

In dimension search, you can't sort based on a different field. For that, you need to use the record search and use the NTK param to specify the field to search and use NS parameter to apply the sorting based on the second field. Please make sure the search NKT field support wildcard search and you ask for only the required field using the field list and you are not doing any spell correction or DYM as this is a type ahead query.